# CPanel and WHM php version change

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have just installed WHM Cpanel on Centos 7

The PHP version is 5.5 is there any way you can downgrade the version to 5.3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can downgrade it if you want php 5.3 version. Please try to run easyapche scripts on your server through command line OR You can run recompile php on your server through WHM, easyapche options